# Get some unexpected changes in xml file when use python/elementtree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Here is the original xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TVAMain xml:lang="en-GB" xmlns="urn:tva:metadata:2010" xmlns:tva2="urn:tva:metadata:extended:2010" xmlns:yv="http://refdata.youview.com/schemas/Metadata/2012-10-16" xmlns:mpeg7="urn:tva:mpeg7:2008" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://refdata.youview.com/schemas/Metadata/2012-09-26 ../schemas/youview_metadata_2012-09-26.xsd"> 
<!-- -->
    <ProgramDescription> .............................
```

I changes some of the content of the xml(but not the one I post here,  those codes should be unchanged), then write to a new xml file, but the new xml file content become like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<TVAMain xmlns="urn:tva:metadata:2010" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://refdata.youview.com/schemas/Metadata/2012-09-26 ../schemas/youview_metadata_2012-09-26.xsd" xml:lang="en-GB">

    <ProgramDescription>....................
```

you can see that the some contents are lost, and the order is also changed, what should I do  in order to avoid any changes to xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes on XML tags do not have a fixed order, changing their ordering doesn't change their meaning.

ElementTree will only write out namespace qualifiers for namespaces actually in use. Your example is very brief, but I suspect it doesn't make use of the `yv` and `mpeg7` namespaces at all.

Comment: Yes, those namespaces are not used in this xml file, but I would like to use this xml file to construct http request and post it to server, if those namespace are lost, when I do the post, it will not succeed, I tried to replace the first two lines with origin lines, then it works, so I wonder how to avoid this kind of 'default' deleting

Comment: So the target server fails to accept the data when the namespaces are missing? That's an error on the part of the server then. You can perhaps manually add those namespaces yourself. See http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm